# Passing String parameter to UITapGestureRecognizer action

Tags: ios, objective-c

In the following code, I'm defining a function that creates arrows (as images) and add these arrows into a view. However, I got a warning that says `Undeclared selector 'method'`. Can someone suggest another way to avoid such warning

```
-(void)createArrow:(NSString*)direction View:(UIView*)view
{
    int x,y;
    NSString *img;
    NSString *method;

    if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]){
        x = 55;
        y = 6;
        _arrow = _arrowUp;
        method = @"upTap";
        img = @"up-arrow.png";
    }else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]){
        x = 55;
        y = 70;
        _arrow = _arrowDown;
        method = @"downTap";
        img = @"down-arrow.png";
    }else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"left"]){
        x = 22;
        y = 39;
        _arrow = _arrowLeft;
        method = @"leftTap";
        img = @"left-arrow.png";
    }else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"right"]){
        x = 90;
        y = 39;
        _arrow = _arrowRight;
        method = @"rightTap";
        img = @"right-arrow.png";
    }

    _arrow = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(x, y, 27, 27)];
    [_arrow setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:img]];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *gest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(method)];
    [_arrow setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [_arrow addGestureRecognizer:gest];
    [view addSubview:_arrow];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avi is correct. But even more simply, why don't you just make `method` of type `SEL`, and in each case, set it directly to the selector you want to fire, then just pass the selector to the gesture recognizer? For example:

```
int x,y;
NSString *img;
SEL method;

if ([direction isEqualToString:@"up"]){
    ...
    method = @selector(upTap);
    ...
} else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"down"]){
    ...
    method = @selector(downTap);
    ...
} else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"left"]){
    ...
    method = @selector(leftTap);
    ...
} else if ([direction isEqualToString:@"right"]){
    ...
    method = @selector(rightTap);
    ...
}

...
UITapGestureRecognizer *gest = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:method];
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Selector names are given as C strings, not NSStrings.  Either change `method` to be a `char *` and drop the leading `@`, or use `NSSelectorFromString(method)`.

Another option is to declare `method` as type SEL and assign it directly in each block of your `if` statement.